# Plotting a parametrically defined vector field

Tags: plotting, visualization, vector-calculus

Let's say that you have a three dimensional surface defined by two parameters. E.g.

$$ S(\theta,\phi) = \{\cos{\theta}\sin{\phi},\sin{\theta}\sin{\phi},\cos{\phi}\} $$

Additionally, you have some normal vectors at each point on the surface, which are defined by

$$N(\theta,\phi)=\frac{\partial S}{\partial \theta} \times \frac{\partial S}{\partial \phi}$$

How could you plot the normal vectors on the surface in *Mathematica*? I have tried:

```
surfacedata = Flatten[Table[mysurface[u, v], {u, 0, 2Pi},{v, 0, Pi}], 1]
normaldata =  Flatten[Table[mynormals[u, v], {u, 0, 2Pi},{v, 0, Pi}], 1]
ListVectorPlot3D[{surfacedata,normaldata}]
```

but to no avail.

Comment: The *Mathematica* code for `mysurface` and `mynormals` is missing. `2Pi` should be `2 Pi`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can plot the surface and the vector fields separately and then combine them together.

Here is an example. Consider the spherical radius r can be written as function $r(\theta,\phi)$:

```
mysurface[θ_, ϕ_] = 
 FullSimplify[Re[SphericalHarmonicY[3, 2, θ, ϕ]], 
  Assumptions -> {θ ∈ Reals, ϕ ∈ Reals}]

(*
1/4 Sqrt[105/(2 π)] Cos[θ] Cos[2 ϕ] Sin[θ]^2
*)
```

Then the surface can be plotted using `SphericalPlot3D`

```
p1 = SphericalPlot3D[
  mysurface[θ, ϕ], {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 
   2 π}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]]
```

[image]

Now we construct the r in Cartesian coordinates

```
mysurfaceXYZ[x_, y_, z_] = 
  FullSimplify[
   TransformedField["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", 
    mysurface[θ, ϕ], {r, θ, ϕ} -> {x, y, z}]];
```

and the surface in Cartesian coordinates satisfies the equation `mysurfaceXYZ[x,y,z]=sqrt[x^2+y^2+z^2]`, which defines a scalar field.

```
scalerField = 
  Simplify[(Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] - mysurfaceXYZ[x, y, z])*(Sqrt[
     x^2 + y^2 + z^2])];
```

The scaling factor `Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]` is just to make the scalar have a more uniform value at different r.

Then the vector field can be constructed easily

```
vectorField = D[scalerField, {{x, y, z}}];
```

Now we can use the VectorPlot3D to plot the norms. The `RegionFunction` can be used to confine the vector field to near the surface

```
VectorPlot3D[vectorField, {x, -1/2, 1/2}, {y, -1/2, 1/2}, {z, -1/2, 
  1/2}, VectorPoints -> 50, 
 RegionFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z}, 
   Abs[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] - mysurfaceXYZ[x, y, z]] <= 0.05 && 
    Abs[x] >= 0.02 && Abs[y] >= 0.02 && Abs[z] >= 0.02], 
 VectorScale -> 0.05]
```

[image]

Finally, combine them together we have

[image]